# Should I invest in learning tmux if I solo code or is it mainly useful for pair programmers?

Tags: tmux

Just what the main question says.  I'm mainly a solo programmer.  Tmux looks interesting but I want to ask the seasoned veterans.. is tmux an every day tool? Or is it just for when you need to pair program?

Comment: [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) isn’t programming-specific; it basically creates a sort of “virtual machine”, so it could be used for a multitude of purposes.

Comment: Is there a reason I got downvoted.. this is or is close to my first post on here.. do I misunderstand the point of superuser.com?.. am I not supposed to ask general questions regarding specific applications?

Comment: *>  do I misunderstand the point of superuser.com?*   It’s certainly possible; it depends on [your perspective](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations/1281#1281).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also find tmux extremely useful as a solo Ruby on Rails developer. I used to develop locally on two machines, a Mac Pro at home and a Macbook Air while traveling: keeping them in sync (rvm, rubies, gems, etc.) used to take considerable time. Not to mention whenever I forgot to push changes to github on one of the machines.

On top of this, from time to time I have to do quick fixes from Windows machines. I ended up renting a VPS (for convenience, I could have done the same on my Mac Pro) and always developing remotely in an SSH session. Tmux is **great** for this, especially when used in conjunction with [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator). I can now move from one machine to another just by attaching tmux to an existing session.

Highly recommended reading: [tmux: Productive Mouse-Free Development](http://pragprog.com/book/bhtmux/tmux)

Once you have gotten used to tmux, and configured it to your needs, it becomes an indispensable tool.

Answer (score 1):

To me, solo programmer, it is very useful for multiple tabs. Others may say that any decent terminal emulator do tabs, but to me keyboard >> mouse.